# Running Jasmine on a Jenkins CI server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, continuous-integration, jasmine

I would like to run jasmine, for our Ruby on Rails client side, on a Jenkins CI server machine using `rake jasmine:ci`. Ideally, I would like it not to use any browser, alternatively if I try to run it with firefox v21 installed, it fails to get connection (I believe this is a known issue).

So to sum my short questions:

1. Is there a stable way to run it without invoking a browser?
2. Does anyone know if the firefox issue has been resolved?
3. I believe JASMINE_BROWSER can control which browser will be used, however I've failed to find instructions what are its legal values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using phantomjs? It would allow you to not invoke a browser. Looks like this [guard-phantomjs-jasmine](https://github.com/stas/guard-phantomjs-jasmine) on Github has the ability to work with jasmine. The documentation has a usecase for CI. Hope that helps!